# How to compress json response size in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, mysql, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have a **firebase callable function** that takes data from a sql cloud database (mysql).

this is the code:

```
// Get records
exports.getRecords = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // get data
  const table_name = data.table_name

  return mysqlPromise.createPool(db.connectionOptions)
    .then(pool => {    
      return pool.query(`
        SELECT * FROM ${table_name};`
      )
    })
    .then(res => {
      return { result: res };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', error);
    });
});
```

If I run the function on a table with few rows (up to 10000) it works perfectly, **but if the table is bigger (100K records) the execution fails showing a "CORS error".**

Analyzing the response, I noticed that the response size on a query that requires 100K rows is around **25MB**.

I know that the limit quota of the firebase functions is 10MB for each response, and I am pretty sure that the error is due to that (even if CORS sounds strange).

The question is:

**"Is there any way to run that query that returns a 100k rows json to me?"**

maybe I have to compress the response or else ... **what is the best solution?**

Thanks in advance! :)